# How to sort this error: random_sample() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

```
##Try to add noise to an image
noisemask = np.random.random_sample(0,1,size=img.shape)
```

Comment: Did you [read the docs?](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random_sample.html)

Answer (score 0):

you need two parenthesis like this :

```
np.random.random_sample((2,2))
```

The function random_sample can only take one argument, but this can be tuple. 
**Example :**

```
>>> np.random.random_sample((3, 2, 2))
array([[[0.31023678, 0.42002874],
    [0.19361976, 0.69127369]],

   [[0.33898072, 0.70568721],
    [0.13130574, 0.41155647]],

   [[0.45329345, 0.29288644],
    [0.06413031, 0.15443909]]])
```

Comment: this gives me 'invalid syntax'  for the = sign

Comment: Can you send the code you use ?